# How can I override file featured-image-first.php of Avada theme

Tags: child-theme, theme-customizer

I use the Avada theme, and I have created a child theme (Customweb) for it.

I tried to override the file:

`wp-content/themes/Avada/includes/lib/inc/templates/featured-image-first.php`

And I try create that file in at:

`wp-content/themes/Customweb/includes/lib/inc/templates/featured-image-first.php`

But it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Child themes let you override templates loaded via WordPress' template loading mechanism, e.g. `get_template_part` or the main theme templates such as `index.php` and `single.php`.

***But they can't be used to replace arbitrary PHP files or assets.***

If a theme loads a template file using `require` or `include`, WordPress cannot intercept this and replace it with a child theme version.

If this is the case, then you will need to find an alternative method to achieve your goal. Check with the themes documentation, the author may have provided a method to do this, such as an option or filter, or you may need to fork the theme.

Comment: Thank you  so much!